# Is there a simple C library for 3d rotations with minimal rounding error?

Tags: c, algorithm, rotation, linear-algebra

A naive implementation of vector rotation in 3d gives huge rounding errors, especially when multiple rotations around different axis are performed. A [simple 1-axis example](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7797910/) shows the basic problem. I have a code where I rotate points around x- and y- axis a few times. In some cases, I get errors in the second decimal place (e.g. length of the vector is 1 before rotations and 0.9 after). I'd be happy with relative errors `< 1e-5`.

```
void Rotate_x(double data[3], double agl) {
    agl *= M_PI/180.0;
    double c = cos(agl);    double s = sin(agl);
    double tmp_y = c*data[1] - s*data[2];
    double tmp_z = s*data[1] + c*data[2];
    data[1] = tmp_y;        data[2] = tmp_z;
}
```

Can someone point me to a **library or some code** that rotates points around the **coordinate axis** with minimal error?

Everything I found were bloated linear algebra libraries that are overkill for my purposes.

**Edit**:
I went to `long double` precision and [combined rotations](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7802546/) to improve errors. With doubles I was not fully satisfied (`1e-3` relative error in worst case). That was the easiest solution an it works okay. Still wouldn't mind a nice library that does rotations in regular double precision accurately.

Comment: Maybe you could convert your points to polar coordinates - then composing rotations is trivial and should not accumulate precision errors. After you are done with rotations, transform back to cartesian.

Comment: Very clean code; well done!

Comment: The problem is certainly not precision.  Suggest the problem is poor quality trig functions.  You should not experience anywhere near the precision lost you report unless the trig functions are poor.

Answer (score 2):

1. better precision variables are not enough

   - you need more precise sin,cos functions to improve accuracy
   - so make your own functions via Taylor series expansion
   - and use that ... then compare the results
   - and increase the polynomial order until accuracy stop raising or start dropping again
2. if you are applying many transformations on the same data

   - then create cumulative transform matrix
   - then check if it is orthogonal/orthonormal
   - and repair if not (with use of cross product)
   - I use this for 3D render object matrices (many cumulative transforms over time)
   - but in your case this can also increase error (if chosen wrong order of axises during correction)
   - this is better suited to ensure that object will stay the same size/shape over time ...

**[edit1] test**

- I took your code to Borland BDS2006 compile as win32 app
- and the result is:
- `original: (0.0000000000000000000,1.0000000000000000000,0.0000000000000000000)`
- `rotated:  (0.0000000000000000000,0.9999999999999998890,-0.0000000000000000273)`
- also do not forget if your sin,cos taking radians (as usuall for C/C++) then add this to Rotate
- `agl*=M_PI/180.0;`
- What compiler/platform are you using?

This is how mine Rotate looks like

```
void Rotate(double *data,double agl)
    {
    agl*=M_PI/180.0;
    double c = cos(agl);    double s = sin(agl);
    double tmp_y = c*data[1] - s*data[2];
    double tmp_z = s*data[1] + c*data[2];
    data[1] = tmp_y; data[2] = tmp_z;
    }
```

**[edit2] 32/64 bit comparison**

```
[double] //64bit floating point
(0.0000000000000000000,1.0000000000000000000,0.0000000000000000000)
(0.0000000000000000000,0.9999999999999998890,-0.0000000000000000273)
[float] //32bit floating point
(0.0000000000000000000,1.0000000000000000000,0.0000000000000000000)
(0.0000000000000000000,0.9999999403953552246,-0.0000000146747787255)
```

Comment: So the easiest thing for me was to switch to `long double` for everything and use the `sinl()` and `cosl()` versions of the trigonometric functions. I needed PI in long double precision as well. That gave me enough for my purposes. 

To store the Euler angles separately and calculate Cartesian coordinates, whenever I need them might be a good solution, too. For now I didn't want to get involved that much. After all it was a relatively simple application.

Thanks for your input! Great suggestions.